# How to create and save pdf file using CORDOVA on mobile device

Tags: cordova, pdf, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, jspdf

I am trying to create and save PDF file on mobile device. I am using "Ionic" framework with jsPdf. 
When I run the script on browser it creates PDF file and downloaded on local machine. But I don't know how to save that PDF document on mobile local directories. I tried following code.

```
var pdfOutput = pdf.output("blob");

ocument.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
                 alert('device is ready, lets do some file reading pdf');
                 $cordovaFile.createFile(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, pdfOutput, true)
                 .then(function (success) {
                     alert('successfully created pdf file');
                  }, function (error){
                 alert('file write error' + error); 
              }); });
```

Can anybody please help me on this ? Also it will be great if anyone tell me the process of creating application folder and store all pdf files inside that folder.

Comment: @user31368884 suggest you to have a look at this link - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use JsPDF its very easy to integrate with cordova url is https://parall.ax/products/jspdf
Step 1  download the JSPDF project code, and copy the jspdf library from the “dist” directory into your cordova project where you are keeping all the js libraries  t.  I put it into the www/jslib.  Then, be sure to include the library inside of your main HTML file.

sample code

```
  //FIRST GENERATE THE PDF DOCUMENT
  console.log("generating pdf...");
  var doc = new jsPDF();

  doc.text(20, 20, 'HELLO!');

  doc.setFont("courier");
  doc.setFontType("normal");
  doc.text(20, 30, 'This is a PDF document generated using JSPDF.');
  doc.text(20, 50, 'YES, Inside of cordova!');

  var pdfOutput = doc.output();
  console.log( pdfOutput );

  //NEXT SAVE IT TO THE DEVICE'S LOCAL FILE SYSTEM
  console.log("file system...");
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

     console.log(fileSystem.name);
     console.log(fileSystem.root.name);
     console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);

     fileSystem.root.getFile("test.pdf", {create: true}, function(entry) {
        var fileEntry = entry;
        console.log(entry);

  entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
     writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
     console.log("write success");
  };

        console.log("writing to file");
           writer.write( pdfOutput );
        }, function(error) {
           console.log(error);
        });

     }, function(error){
        console.log(error);
     });
  },
  function(event){
   console.log( evt.target.error.code );
  });
```

Comment: thanks for your code, I tried this and not getting any error, can you please tell me where I will find the test.pdf file on my android device ?

Comment: @user3136884 did you ever find the file?

Comment: I´m having the same issue and the answer is only to create and save

Answer (score -1):

install `cordova plugin add cordova-pdf-generator`

use the following code.

```
 $scope.Function_name = function() {

        var opts = {
            type: "share", //Open a context menu and ask the user what to do next (print, mail, etc..).
            fileName: 'v8-tutorial.pdf' //it will use this filename as a place-holder
        }

        pdf.fromData('<html><h1>Hello World</h1></html>', opts)
            .then((status) => console.log('success->', status))
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));

        // End here

    }
```